# Categories field that allows duplicate values

Tags: fieldtypes

I have a categories field where I would like to be able to include the same category more than once. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Could you please tell more about the reason/intention behind? Perhaps we can find a workaround.

Comment: Example: a play-list where the tracks are categories, and I want to be able to have the same track more than once in a play-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably go with a Matrix field, with one block type containing the Categories field. This would also allow you to include other fields for some extra meta data to distinguish one category assignment from another, otherwise identical one.

To use your playlist example, the Matrix blocks would let you set the order of the tracks as well.

Comment: Great minds thinking alike! Categories would let me set the order as well, but it is maybe even more explicit with Matrix blocks